Android Studio Constantly Prompts Me "Can't determine a type for tag"
Here is my current code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChartX"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/line_chart_height" />

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChartY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/line_chart_height" />

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChartZ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/line_chart_height" />
</LinearLayout>


Here is my gradle code:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.imugraphapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.imugraphapp"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")
    implementation("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

}

My Problem
I have been trying to get my code for this app to work, but I am constantly given this problem regarding this section of my code: Can't determine type for tag '<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart android:id="@+id/lineChartX" android:layout_height="@dimen/line_chart_height" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>'
I have checked and debugged gradle, watched countless tutorials and explanations, and I have debugged this section numerous times. However, this error will not be resolved no matter what I do. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue so that my app can run?your text
